# Best api for connecting to MS Sql server without creating additional tables to the database

Tags: sql, api

I want to build a small api for an existing MS Sql server in my local network. I am not planning this api to do INSERT, UPDATE query on the sql server. Just a small SELECT query. Mostly for counting the rows in a table for a date range.
I don't want the api to create any default tables in the database either while setting up. Just to perform a select query on get request. The sql raw query is just fine for me.

**Which APIs should I look for this purpose?**
My intention is to get live production from the server and display those in mobile/desktop app.

Currently I have achieved this using `pyodbc` package in python and I can make a tkinter app out of it. But I want more advanced setup for a flutter app. So building an api is much better I suppose.

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers in the world, but Sql Server itself doesn't provide web/HTTP access without some client language in between.

Comment: I just want a simple method, so I can start with the documentation 

Comment: Sticking with Python, you can start with a tutorial on Flask, and then integrate your pyodbc code.  https://pypi.org/project/Flask/

Comment: If I try to connect it with django, will django default models will be build on the databse? Just found out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/mssql-django-samples/mssql-django-samples/